# Handsontable dropdowns hidden in overflow:auto div

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm trying to use dropdowns in handsontable 0.17.0. The table is large so I have it in a width and height limited div with overflow: auto so that it gets scrollbars. However, dropdown cells don't work because the dropdown popup won't overflow the div and you can't scroll the div to see the dropdown because clicking outside of the dropdown closes it. How can I use dropdown cells in scrolling HOTs?

I've taken the dropdown example from HOT documentation and wrapped it in a size limited div:

HTML

```
<div style="height: 90px; width: 200px; overflow: auto">
  <div id="example1" class="hot handsontable htColumnHeaders"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: [
      ["Nissan", 2012, "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2012, "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2012, "black"],
    ],
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color'],
    columns: [
      {},
      {type: 'numeric'},
      {
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'black', 'white']
      },
    ]
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6cb3djx/

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Your fiddle works fine for me. The dropdown appears and I just scroll down to see the values.

Comment: I'm using the latest Firefox. I need to support the latest Firefox, chrome and IE 11/edge. It didn't even work in Firefox so I didn't try the others. I can say the issue is the same on mobile Firefox and mobile chrome, not that mobile is usable, but I'm away from my desktop now.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the desktop versions? I can't replicate the issue and haven't heard of any bugs like this yet.

Comment: I will, but I'm traveling and away from desktops so on Sunday or Monday I can do it. I assumed it was for everyone. If that's not the case I'll check my stylesheets for any z order as well.

Comment: I just attached a screenshot from Firefox 40.0.3 on Windows 10. It looks the same on Firefox 40 on Windows 7 as well. Sometimes the dropdown appears over the scrollbar, sometimes not. As for my earlier comment about stylesheets, I realized of course my stylesheets can't be a problem as it happens on jsfiddle as well.

Comment: I would post it on the issues page of the github project. They're pretty fast to get you an answer on things that are considered bugs. I still can't replicate it so I'm not sure how you're getting this to happen but maybe they'll have seen it too and have an answer.

Comment: Every browser I've tried on the 3 devices I've tested have this issue. It looks like it's already being tracked at https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2098 even though it's phrased a little differently.

Comment: No I think that was a different issue. They didn't like that you had to scroll down to see all the values of the dropdown. I would still post it as a new issue since I haven't seen this happen before

Comment: I thought maybe because the symptoms were the same but the way they got there was different... But I did create a more direct issue https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2838. Specifically I haven't seen it work anywhere on any browser. Only you have said it works. I've tried 3 machines and 3 different browsers. Well, you can scroll to see the values but only with mouse wheel. it doesn't pop out of the limited table and you can't click on scroll bar.

Comment: Oh you can scroll to see the values? Sorry, that's what I had expected the behavior to be. I thought when you said that they don't overflow the div, that they were being hidden. They do overflow the div, it just doesn't scroll is what you meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddling in the browser, I was able to show the complete pulldown.

There is a `<div>` with the 2 classes "handsontable htColumnHeaders". You simply need to add the following CSS to your page, then the pulldown is shown:

```
/* Pulldown can break out of handsontable boundary */
.htColumnHeaders {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

This overwrites the direct HTML attribute style="....; overflow: hidden".
Hint: do not restrict to overflow-y, as this will not overwrite overflow (without "-y").